# Opencart extension installer menu missing from admin panel

Tags: installation, opencart

I have to install a module from the admin panel but the Extensions -> Extension Installer is missing from my admin panel.I cant figure out why this is happening.Can anybody help me?

Comment: Which version of opencart you are using?

Answer (score 2):

As per your opencart version `1.5.6.4` there is not any option for extension  installer. This feature is available in `2.0 and above`